# Downloading html file through webrequest from url(html file is downloading,but the content is not showing, it is showing empty)

Tags: c#, .net

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
    string filepath = "https://mycity.sulekha.com/bmm2015/html/terms.html"; // /downloadpath/files/download.html
    string sResult = objRender.HtmlSnippet(filepath);
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.Charset = "";
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=download.html");
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.html";    
    response.Charset = "";
    response.Write(sResult.ToString());
    response.End();

}
```

Comment: The dowwnload is vnd.  See : https://www.developershome.com/wap/xhtmlmp/xhtml_mp_tutorial.asp?page=mimeTypesFileExtension&force_isolation=true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.